# viewController nib's view is nil?

Tags: iphone, ios, view, xib

I used to create viewController/views programmatically only.

Using xib is harder than I expected.

I found that self.view of an xib or any other subview is initially nil.

```
I created the viewController by [[MyViewController alloc] init]  
and tried to [myViewController.imageView setImage: image];  //imageView is nil  

NSLog(@"%p", myViewController.view); // access view here
[myViewController.imageView setImage: image]; //works now
```

I feel I'm missing something very basic. What would it be?

Comment: Are you trying to access the view in the init method or after viewDidLoad fires?

Comment: When using an additional view controller linked to a xib, you have to make sure that you like the xibs view outlet to the controller. Have you done this?

Comment: **---OFF** you wrote: _Using xib is harder than I expected._ are you just kidding, aren't you?

Comment: not kidding.. can you take a look at comments below 'banded''s answer?

Answer (score 1):

As described in [the documentation for `UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the views are lazily loaded when you first access the `view` property.  The earliest you can reference them is in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this happens when I try to access the view before viewDidLoad fires, for instance trying to access this in the init method of the view controller.  If this is the case, wait until after viewDidLoad fires to access the view.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I could then just use the above hack maybe?, or I can pass the image to init. If I define -(id) initWithImage:(UIImage*)image, would it not use xib file anymore?

Comment: You can use -(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil image:(UIImage *)image and call super -(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil in that method if you would like to still use the nib.  You will want to retain the image and set it after viewDidLoad fires in this case.

Comment: actually -(id)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image { [super init]; ..} worked fine.. is it a surprise?

Comment: This is a bit surprising that you were able to load a nib file without the using the super constructor that I mentioned in my last post.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibname:@"mynibname" bundle:nil]
```

in this format to allocate the proper view ....try it